# Libgdx AssetManager works in eclipse but not on a runnable jar

Tags: java, jar, libgdx, assets, asset-management

The code looks something like this:

```
if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android) path = "data/images/";
if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Desktop) path = "./bin/data/images";
```

(if i use "data/images/" for Desktop, i get a crash).

`assetmanager.load(path + fileName)`, `assetmanager.finishLoading()` and later `assetmanager.get(path + fileName)` works perfectly in Eclipse and also on Android, but when i create a runnable .jar and launch it from console, i get `Asset not loaded: ./bin/data/images/image.jpg`. So for some reason it cannot access the data folder inside my .jar archive. How do i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Open your jar with 7zip or something like that and look, if the "data/images" folder is there. I guess there is something wrong with the "dependencies" and "order and export"- settings of the project.

Comment: Yes, it is there. Also, when i add a folder named bin/data/images/ to the same folder that the .jar file is in, it will work. But i'd still prefer it to take the images from inside the .jar.

Comment: IT seems, like it does not want to use the internal `FileHanlde`... Just a try: Give the `load` method also the class (`Texture.class`)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, i didn't copy the code from my project. Actually i am using it like this: assetManager.load(images[i].path(), Texture.class)

Comment: And you are sure, that the path you get is right? Also: Why do you use "./bin/data/images" for Desktop and "data/images" for android? What is the crashe you are getting?

Comment: The paths are correct, for example this one will work: `./bin/data/images/h.jpg`. When i use `data/images` for desktop, the crash looks something like this: `Asset not loaded: data/images/h.jpg`. I understand that the `./bin/` hack isn't the correct way to do things, but for some reason it's the only one that has been working for me. It's really weird..

Comment: Did you use the libgdx setup ui to create the project or did you set dependencies etc. manually? If the adroid version is working and it is working in eclipse, i guaess something is worng with the dependencies...

Comment: I used the app, but for some reason the desktop assets folder was not getting files from my android project. I deleted and replaced the desktop assets folder. It is working now, because all of the android's assets are availbable in there, too. Could there still be something wrong with that folder?
Edit: I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but i am not using gradle. Instead i generated the needed Eclipse build files.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are not using gradle. Therefore you need to add the dependencies manually. I am not sure if it is the same wit hthe new libgdx version, but before libgdx version 1.0 (i used this setup with Version 0.9) it worked like in this tutorial (http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) **ATTENTION!** This tutorial is outdated, i am not sure, if it stil works this way, if not i suggest to create the project with setup ui+gradle and copy your source code.

Comment: Well, it appers that when using `Gdx.files.internal("data/images/").list()` on a desktop app, it always returns an empty list. I guess `./bin/data/images/` was not affected by that. That is also why `"data/images/"` only worked on Android. The solution is to add every image manually, instead of looping through the folder. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you solved this issue now? If fthats the case, please add the solution as an answer, it may help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appers that when using `Gdx.files.internal("data/images/").list()` on a desktop app, it always returns an empty list. I guess `./bin/data/images/` was not affected by that. That is also why `"data/images/"` only worked on Android. The solution is to add every image manually, instead of looping through the folder. Thank you for your help!